# Change debug shortcuts in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using `Yosemite` and would like to change the default shortcuts when debugging `JS` in `Chrome Developer Tools`, to match the same shortcuts i use in `Netbeans`.

For instance, in Developer Tools the default behaviour of `F8` in a breakpoint is resume script execution, and i would like to use F8 to step into next function.

Is this possible without remapping keys at system level ?

Comment: I dont imagine this is possible without intercepting the keypress events based on the active window (chrome) -> translating them -> and forwding to chrome.. seems easier to just get used to the current setup. Alternatively, change your netbeans shortcuts

Comment: Problem is to have different setups in server / client side, i end up to press the wrong key in Chrome ;)

Comment: ;) Asking to resolve human error then eh! ;]